# ASP.NET database which relations

Tags: database

Is it good approach to make this way database in ASP.NET MVC?
I am using intermediary ention between entions instead many to many relation.

[image]

Should I use relations many to many and use generic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fine,

you have to do a bit more work manually, but you gain control over your entities.

A many-to-many relationship requires an intermediary table to make the associations.

If you use a many-to-many relation, EF will create an intermediary table anyway

Comment: @marylin17 Yes, it is the correct way to model a many-to-many relationship in a relational database.